# Error putting S3 policy: MalformedPolicy: Policy has invalid resource terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I keep seeing this error and clearly cannot understand what the problem is. My IAM policy is as follows :

```
  data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_admin_access" {
    statement {
    sid    = "AllowGroupAAccess"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:ListBucket"
    ]

    resources = local.s3_arn_etl_bucket_array

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::598889206234:user/tester123@tt.com"]
    }
  }

  statement {
    sid    = "DenyAllOtherUsers"
    effect = "Deny"
    actions = [
      "s3:*"
    ]

    resources = local.s3_arn_etl_bucket_array


    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }

    condition {
      test     = "StringNotEquals"
      variable = "aws:PrincipalArn"
      values   = [""]
    }
  }
}
```

```
       resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "s3_admin_access" {
        for_each = data.terraform_remote_state.s3_buckets.outputs.map_s3_bucket_id
         bucket   = each.value
         policy   = data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3_admin_access.json
}
```

locals.tf

```
 s3_buckets_arn       = data.terraform_remote_state.s3_buckets.outputs.map_s3_bucket_arn


 s3_arn_etl_bucket_array = [for key, value in local.s3_buckets_arn : "${value}/*"]
```

my outputs.tf is as follows :

```
  output "map_s3_bucket_arn" {
  value = {
  for k, v in module.s3_etl_module : k => v.bucket_arn }
  }


 output "map_s3_bucket_id" {
 value = {
 for k, v in module.s3_etl_module : k => v.bucket_id }
 }
```

Am not really sure what is wrong with this policy. The name of my buckets are correct and I have also checked the arn for each s3 bucket and this is correct so am really unsure of what to do here.

This is the error I see :

****Error: Error putting S3 policy: MalformedPolicy: Policy has invalid resource
│   status code: 400, request id: 5DZH2CZYDQYSDCCH, host id: e0URLuxPDKuImoHwz4GMoLqfWxdqV+okVbBJDWBcZkdUhj2x6g4s2wac5askmQl+TMeDkPnknDQ=
│
│   with aws_s3_bucket_policy.s3_admin_access["s3_published_bucket"],
│   on iam_policy_s3_admin_access.tf line 1, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "s3_admin_access":
│    1: resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "s3_admin_access" {**
│

**Error: Error putting S3 policy: MalformedPolicy: Policy has invalid resource
│   status code: 400, request id: 5DZJBE0ADPGP04JY, host id: bOe69lh+36ng7b8iFcteifnuwRyhyKA6Hi4XV4dX8jediXonGQ6vRA0gnDnmNCP6LcwFOkKy6bquIaWFM1weOw==
│
│   with aws_s3_bucket_policy.s3_admin_access["s3_raw_bucket"],
│   on iam_policy_s3_admin_access.tf line 1, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "s3_admin_access":
│    1: resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "s3_admin_access" {**

**Error: Error putting S3 policy: MalformedPolicy: Policy has invalid resource
│   status code: 400, request id: 5DZZVBEJY6TQ4720, host id: u4PN0bDI/OjSgfWs8KMWr0CYCMjzDEvCol6wIA/zZBgPlIPZTTX4bDVm3Zgetd5B+EqG2jV1H4I=
│
│   with aws_s3_bucket_policy.s3_admin_access["s3_processed_bucket"],
│   on iam_policy_s3_admin_access.tf line 1, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "s3_admin_access":
│    1: resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "s3_admin_access" {**

local s3_arn_etl_bucket_array gives me the following in my policy :

```
  data-s3-raw-bucket-source/*",
  data-s3-published-bucket-source/*",
  data-s3-processed-bucket-source/*",
```

Comment: Please add the code and not terraform plan output.

Comment: Added the terraform code @MarkoE

Comment: Have you checked the value of your local s3_arn_etl_bucket_array? Is it what you expect?
Also, the error you provided is not helpful, can you give the whole error message?

Comment: Can you add how you have defined the local variable?

Comment: It is in the question if you look at locals.tf @MarkoE

Comment: ok so the issue is in the s3_arn_etl_bucket_array. These are not ARNs. You should further investigate the module s3_etl_module output bucket_arn. Right now it returns bucket names and not ARN